# Usage of default <option> in React required select element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm struggling with select element in React (also with weak documentation about that).

Is there any 'native' option to use controlled `<select>`, with placeholder hack (`<option value={null} />`) ?

I have a feeling that this input type is pretty useless with React.

The main goals are:
- use native input in sake of support (mobile browsers, unification of validation & styling, straight-forward stack)
- have a required select input
- have a placeholder in select input

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally solved!

Important thing is to convert empty string to a null when setting value and null to empty value when getting it from state, so:

```
  <select
    required
    onChange={e => this.setState({select: e.target.value || null})}
    value={this.state.select || ''}
  >
    <option value=''>None</option>
  ...
```